# Building with GCC 10 on Ubuntu 22 leads to missing library (GLIBC_2.34) when running executable on Ubuntu 20

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, gcc

So I have a VM I upgraded from Ubuntu 20 to 22. This VM is used as my development environment at work, on which I build apps, which should run on target Ubuntu 20 machines.
Now, back when my VM ran Ubuntu 20, I was able to build the apps and run them on the target machines. However, after upgrading it to Ubuntu 22, building the apps on my VM and attempting to run them on the target machines (which are still on 20) produces the following error:

```
usr/lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found
```

I checked the differences between the GCC-10 compilers on both machines and saw a slight difference:

The Ubuntu 20 has the `gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) 10.3.0` version.

The Ubuntu 22 has the `gcc (Ubuntu 10.3.0-15ubuntu1) 10.3.0` version

Although both are 10.3.0 based, my guess is that this slight difference might be the source of the problem.

Now I tried uninstalling the prebuilt GCC-10 and download and install the Ubuntu 20 GCC-10 deb file, but got caught in a dependency hell.

So, my question is whether there's a way to install this specific release on 22, although originally destined for 20. Alternatively, is there a way to add this missing library locally. Note that I can mess with my VM, but not with the target machines.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with `gcc`, but it is complaining about `glibc`, which is version [2.35](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/jammy/glibc) in Ubuntu 22.04 but version [2.31](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/glibc) in Ubuntu 20.04.  So, it is the library that is different.  I certainly wouldn't play with installing another Ubuntu's gcc or libc.  Many dependencies rely on it and you will mess up your system.  I would suggest if the target machine is Ubuntu 20.04, you should get a new VM with that version.  Don't mess with `gcc` or `libc` at all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856438/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-glibc-version the problem is that these versions of ubuntu use different `glibc` versions